# GCP Bucket or Filestore to use as a replacement for Azure Blob Storage to mount on kubernetes Pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, storage, google-kubernetes-engine

We are migrating from Azure to GCP. In Azure we use Azure Blob Storage to mount on k8s using PV-PVC.

When learning GCP, I found that Azure Blob equivalent of GCP is Bucket, but it is not mountable using PV-PVC. But GCP Filestore can be used to mount on k8s Pod using PV-PVC.

Mounting of GCP Bucket is possible through gcsfuse / mount command as part of init script / app start shell script.

The mounted storage is used for application logging as well as storing some business related data.

I tried both Bucket and Filestore, which is working for demo application.

Which is recommended to use with GKE to mount on Pod? Bucket or Filestore

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to please update the status of question if any of below answer resolve your issue.

Comment: For now we went ahead with using Filestore. Recently I think FUSE CSI driver (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/cloud-storage-fuse-csi-driver) was introduced, so we may think of using it in future.

Comment: It’s now in GA it was there so great you can leverage that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GCS Fuse** is good for storing the **logging** data if you are Ready with **latency**.

When you have **business related** data if it's essential you have to handle the **retry** **strategy** with the **GCS fuse**.

On the other side with **Filestore** i think the minimum provisioning will be **1** TB so if you can afford and have requirement of that much data it will be a good option.

Also, filestore supports **ReadWriteMany** so if you have that requirement go for it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do have ReadWriteMany requirement. But are you suggesting read / write by multiple pods having bucket mounted is not possible ?

Comment: that's possible however considering the latency also also file locking if you need, you can use fuse with init-consatiner sync before and after as you want. if non critical workload you have you can use that

Answer (score 1):

You can mount GCS buckets with PV/PVC if the cluster is on GKE via Google's Cloud Storage FUSE CSI driver. It has examples in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/cloud-storage-fuse-csi-driver#provision-static). It also supports mounting GCS buckets as CSI ephemeral volumes.

Have a look at [csi-gcs](https://github.com/ofek/csi-gcs) for another unofficial option.

Comment: Yes, we are doing POC using Google's Cloud Storage FUSE CSI driver. I think it was not ready / available when I asked this question. One thing I want to know is that how much ephemeral storage to allocate for fuse side-car container. The application service conatiner is processing files sized from few MBs to few GBs.